# Fragment crashing on reload

Tags: android, multithreading, nullpointerexception, fragment

My Problem is, on the second reload my fragment is crashing with a NullPointerException. The exception leads to **FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();**

**LogCat**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at xx.xx.wamomu.ui.MeasurementFragment.refresh(MeasurementFragment.java:344)
        at xx.xx.wamomu.ui.MeasurementFragment$9.run(MeasurementFragment.java:392)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

At the creation of the fragment I'm launching a loop as Thread, that is listening for an incoming event.

```
public void threadloop(){

    (new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.interrupted())
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    Log.d("LOOP", "TIMEOUT OVER");

                    if (swtch == 1) {

                       refresh();
                        swtch = 0;
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // ooops
                }
        }
    })).start();

}
```

With the **refresh()** function I'm trying to reload the actual fragment. I'm using this method in a dialog and after the dialog is dismissed, the refresh is working perfectly.

```
public void refresh() {

    Log.e("RESUMED", "OK");
    Thread.interrupted();
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    Log.e("CURRENTTHREADREFRESH", "" + Thread.currentThread());
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        changeFragment = new MeasurementFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.fl_content_frame, changeFragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();


}
```

In the fragment, the first refresh is working, but the second seems to crash the fragment. I'm thinking, that maybe the loop is causing the error, because of this I tried to kill the fragment, mainly to kill the loop-thread. But the Loop does not stop.

Even if I switch to an another fragment, the Thread is not stopping. I tried to stop it in the **onPause()** method, but the loop keeps on running.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Thread.interrupted();
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    Log.e("CURRENTTHREADPAUSE", "" + Thread.currentThread());
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Comment: coordinate the state of your enclosed thread with the state of the enclosing fragment. When fragment cycles to onPause() or to onStop() you need to save/stop the thread state

Comment: `Thread.currentThread()` in `onPause()` will not be your `threadLoop` thread; it will be the application's UI thread, which you probably don't want to be strying to stop.

Comment: @Tanis.7x I created a Thread = loop; and in the threadloop() I did loop = new Thread(...). In the onPause() and onStop() I tried to stop the thread with loop.interrupt(); but it still keeps on listening for the event if I'm switching to an another fragment. The second reload still crashes the fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my main problem, with the fragment crashing. 
I just had to put the

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

in the **onCreate()** method.

*Problem number two, with the thread not stopping is still occuring.*

**Edit:**

Could not solve the problem with the thread, because of this I switched to an ScheduledExecutorService, which is getting stopped in the **onPause()** method.

Comment: Well you need a fragment transaction object to push a fragment. But your log is not fixating on the real problem here. It was a null pointer exception.